# popup window move and minimize using overlay and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, overlay

How to move and minimize popup window using overlay and javascript

```
<wec:overlay id="oViU"
        displayed="#{cc.vch.itemUploadOverlayDisplayed}" hideClose="true"
        hideOpen="true" modal="true"
        rendered="#{cc.vch.itemUploadOverlayRendered}"
        styleClass="fw-overlay-popup-size-432">
```